# Ignore Slashes When Saving a File

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report which picks the account number and name of the report ran and saves it in the reporting location

Some accounts have the classic "trading as" in their name, which in the saved file would be `T/A` - which Microsoft can't save

```
Dim AccCode As Variant, AccName As Variant, MyFileName As Variant, MyfilePath As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet

MyfilePath = "N:\Solutions\Sales Report"
Set ws = Worksheets("PAGE 1-ACCOUNT&CONTACTS")
AccCode = ws.Cells(5, 2).Value
AccName = ws.Cells(6, 2).Value

MyFileName = MyfilePath & "\" & Trim(AccCode) & "_" & Trim(AccName) & ".xlsx"
'
    ChDir _
    MyfilePath
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
    MyFileName _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Does anyone know of a method to ignore/replace any `/` in file names when saving in the above method?

Comment: Have you tried the [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) function?

Comment: I didn't think of that. If you want some free rep, you can add `AccName = Replace(AccName, "/", "-")` under the current `AccName` - that's what my script looks like now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple [`Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) should do the trick.

```
AccName = ws.Cells(6, 2).Value
AccName = Replace(AccName, "/", "-")
```

Answer (score 3):

The following function replaces invalid characters from a file name with an underscore:

```
Public Function CreateValidFilename(ByVal name As String) As String
    Const InvalidChars As String = "/:*?""'<>|"
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(InvalidChars)
        Dim chr As String
        chr = Mid(InvalidChars, i, 1)
        name = Replace(name, chr, "_")
    Next i
    CreateValidFilename = name
End Function
```

Just add a call to it, eg

```
MyFileName = CreateValidFilename(MyFileName)
```

Comment: Thanks - a perfect answer. I would like to change my staff's script as little as possible - so if this is the best answer I'll give it a go

Comment: @Badja writing code is free :) Adding a function more to your project doesn't hurt anybody (neither does the code less clear), but this answer is more complete than the one you selected. With such a function you would avoid any issue with the file name while with a simple replace of `/` as you chose to do, your code will fail as soon as they decide to add a very common char (like `:`, or `?`, or simply `"` to their account names.

Comment: Thanks for this. I do note that the answer is more complete, but as I didn't want to confuse my team member, coupled with the fact that the system we ODBC to can only have `/` as a special character - this project will be good. However I will keep thecode handy as I have a lot more scripts that will need this (i.e not for account names)